# Barby gem not generating qr_code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using the [barby gem documentation](https://github.com/toretore/barby/wiki/Outputters#png), the following is not generating a qr code,

```
require 'barby'
require 'rqrcode'
require 'barby/barcode/qr_code'
require 'barby/outputter/png_outputter'
qr_string = "8076809574693\r\n8076809574693\r\n8076809574693\r\n4017100364013\r\n4017100364013\r\n3017760002707\r\n8076809517706\r\n8013355999488\r\n"
qr_output = Barby::PngOutputter.new(qr_string).to_png
File.open('qrcode.png', 'wb'){|f| f.write qr_output }
```

as it complains on the penultimate line for `qr_output` with
`NoMethodError (undefined method` two_dimensional?' for #String:0x00007f903526c4c0)`
Installed gems

```
gem 'rqrcode', '~> 2.0'
gem 'barby', '~> 0.6.8'
```

*Note: the raw data has all 13 characters of what are EAN-13 codes, when barby, for processing EAN-13 symbology only accepts 12 characters as input and generates the 13th character (control) itself.*

What is mistaken in this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass a string directrly to `PngOutputter`. It must be processed by barby's qr code module first.

```
require 'barby'
require 'rqrcode'
require 'barby/barcode/qr_code'
require 'barby/outputter/png_outputter'
qr_string = "8076809574693\r\n8076809574693\r\n8076809574693\r\n4017100364013\r\n4017100364013\r\n3017760002707\r\n8076809517706\r\n8013355999488\r\n"
qr_data = Barby::QrCode.new(qr_string)
qr_output = Barby::PngOutputter.new(qr_data).to_png
File.open('qrcode.png', 'wb'){|f| f.write qr_output }
```